# Angular is not defined using nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm fairly new to Angular and NodeJS and trying to run a sample website.

From what I understood, to run it I simply need to execute "node app.js".

However, I get the following error:

```
C:\app\app.js:3
angular
^

ReferenceError: angular is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\app\app.js:3:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

My app.js looks like this:

```html
'use strict';

angular
  .module('apmportal', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource'
])
```

The project's structure is:

[image: The project's structure is:]

Here is the index.html:

```
  <!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
  <!-- bower:js -->
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js">
```

App folder structure:

[image]

I should mention that node is installed and I've also ran bower install to install all dependencies.
Clearly I'm missing something here but I just cant figure out what.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot run node app.js because app.js is your front-end file. create server.js outside in your project structure and serve app/index.html from that(you should have index.html inside app folder). then run node server.js

If you don't have idea about set up backend check this project structure

[Project Structure](https://github.com/ajay2507/InstaApp/tree/master/InstaApp)

In my case I have server code in app.js so it would be node app.js in my case